# Why there is a marginTop in NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ...

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/movie_nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/movie_nav_menu" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is `movie_nav_header`:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            imageUrl="@{data.large}">

        </com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But there is a marginTop in NavigationView in my UI.
[image]

I cannot find the method to solve it.
I guess it may be caused by fitsystemwindows, but it doesn't seem to be...

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <include layout="@layout/custome_navigation"/>

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

In java code

```
 DrawerLayout navDrawer = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_drawer_layout);
            if (!navDrawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) navDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
            else navDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

You can set the navigation Drawer `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: I tried to use fitSystemWindows=true，but it cannot to sovlve this problem. You mean no need to use `headerLayout`?

Comment: I can add the link and follow the way because my project in work properly